# How do I address a UNC path in Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, unc

I'm trying to access a UNC share via `irb` on Windows. In the Windows shell it would be

```
\\server\share
```

I tried escaping all of the backslashes.

```
irb(main):016:0> Dir.entries '\\\\server\share'
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - \\server\share
```

and using the IP address instead of the name

```
irb(main):017:0> Dir.entries '\\\\192.168.10.1\share'
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - \\192.168.10.1\share
```

Comment: With 1.9.3 at least, you can just use forward slashes and you don't have to worry about escaping or anything `Dir['//server/share/*']`. Looks a heck of a lot nicer than having to escape all of the backslashes.

Comment: I ran into the problem of trying to use UNC-paths: [UNC not having access (last comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319077/wmi-access-to-unc-paths)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to escape '\' with another '\'

```
Dir.entries('\\\\\\\\192.168.10.1\\\\share')
```

Comment: Oh lord. I had a typo in my path... However, it works with double backslashes. Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 6):

Ruby interprets paths in a [POSIX way](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion), meaning you should use forward slashes when possible.

```
//server/share
```

The trailing slash is unnecessary, just like in native Windows. You can use backslashes, but they have to be [escaped](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences) with another backslash.

```
\\\\server\\share
```

I'd only recommend that when you're passing UNC paths from native programs directly and can't transform them. When I'm mixing Ruby/Windows paths, like in a build script that uses Ruby methods and native Windows apps, which each require different paths, I'll use some helpers:

```
def windows_path(value)
  value.gsub '/', '\\'
end

def posix_path(value)
  value.gsub '\\', '/'
end
```

Always enclose your paths in single quotes, if they're literal, or double-quotes if you're interpolating. Forward slashes tell Ruby to start interpreting a regex. This is a common error for me in irb.

```
irb> File.exists? //server/share
SyntaxError: (irb):2: unknown regexp options - rvr
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the trailing slash. Try `'\\server\share\'`

It's similar to the root directory of a Windows drive. That's `C:\`, not `C:`

Comment: Doesn't work either when doubling the backslashes: irb(main):021:0> Dir.entries('\\\\server\\share\\') Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - \\server\share\