# Is there any way to check if a (UNC path) volume is a Windows DedupVolume or not?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, wmi-query

I wanted to find out if a given volume has Data Deduplication enabled or not.

---

For a local volume this is straightforward using the WMI query:

`select * from MSFT_DedupVolume where Volume='E:\\MountFolder\\DedupVolume'`

---

But for a UNC path as volume name, the WMI query returns nothing (no error, just blank output).

`select * from MSFT_DedupVolume where Volume='\\\\windowsMachine\\E$\\MountFolder\\DedupVolume'`

---

In [wmi-access-to-unc-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319077/wmi-access-to-unc-paths) it is mentioned that

> WMI operations are not allowed to access network resources due to security restrictions in Windows.

Is there any other way to find out if a UNC path volume has Data Deduplication configured or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve the problem.

As the computer name (`windowsMachine`) and the local volume name on that machine (`E:\\MountFolder\\DedupVolume`) are available from the unc path `\\\\windowsMachine\\E$\\MountFolder\\DedupVolume`, it is possible to get the MSFT_DedupVolume information using the powershell command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from MSFT_DedupVolume where Volume='E:\\MountFolder\\DedupVolume'" -Namespace 'root/microsoft/windows/deduplication' -ComputerName 'windowsMachine'
```