# Rails 4: Issue Sending .txt files from local machine to Windows Share

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, unc

I'm currently creating .csv files from a SQL view and writing to

`#{Rails.root}/public/`

which works no problem. In addition, I need to write these generated files to a Windows share in the form of:

`\\NAME-APP.enterprise.company.com\Files`

I've tried `Net::SCP.upload`, `Net::SFTP.start`, `FileUtils`, `rsync`, and even `Dir.entries('share url here`)` just to see if I can see anything in the folder, which generally results in

`No such file or directory @ dir_initialize`

I can map my local computer to the Windows share point, in the form of:

`smb://NAME-APP.enterprise.company.com/Files`

but manually dragging and dropping to there isn't an acceptable solution in this case.

Feel like I've hit a wall and may be overlooking something. Have stumbled across this post but to no avail: [How do I address a UNC path in Ruby on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995370/how-do-i-address-a-unc-path-in-ruby-on-windows)

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

`FileUtils.cp_r('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/davidpardy/development/ror/sbb/oct31week/1a/FST-Export/public/1538791_new.txt', '\\\\NAME-APP\\Files')`

doesn't return an error, but doesn't upload the .txt file to Files.

Comment: Make sure you are using the mount path instead of `smb://...`. If you're on a mac this will look something like `/Volumes/Files...`

Comment: Well the `smb` portion would only be for Windows, since that's where I'm trying to get files to. Did you mean explicitly state the location of the .txt files on Mac? ie `/Volumes/mycomp/dev/RailsApp/public/whatever.txt. Updated my initial question with some extra stuff.

Comment: Right, `smb://...` is just the server address, but you want to know the path you've mounted it to on your file system.  Open up the terminal and run the command `mount`.  You should see something like `//NAME-APP/Files on /Volumes/my_mount_folder (smbfs, nodev, ...)`

Comment: Ahhh interesting, so it should be `FileUtils.cp_r('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/davidpardy/development/ror/sbb/oct31week/1a/FST-Export/public/1538791_new.txt', '/Volumes/OasisFlatFiles')` . Just ran that and it worked! You rock man! Feel free to post as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Awesome! I posted the answer below for you to accept. I'm glad you got passed the wall ;-)

Comment: Haha man I was pulling my hairs out. Definitely learned something new here so that's what matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to use `FileUtils.cp_r(source_file, 'smb://...')` because `smb://...` only represents the server address, not the mount folder on your filesystem.

In the terminal, run the `mount` command to find the path of the mount folder, which is what you'll use in ruby, e.g., `FileUtils.cp_r(source_file, '/Volumes/mount_folder_here...')`.